# can't scale a custom model in three js

Tags: three.js, 3d, scale, react-three-fiber

when i scale the custom model it works , but its not effecting when it comes with particles. if you see this video you can understand waht i am saying .
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-48ad5.appspot.com/o/2023-09-19%2010-01-56.mp4?alt=media&token=c0682bcc-cd3a-4af9-8b36-6cfff45bd4b2

```
const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 16, 16);
        const particles = [];
        const originalPositions = [];
        const originalMaterials = [];
        const highlightMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    
    
    
    
        loader.load('/mesh3.glb', (gltf) => {
          const model = gltf.scene;
          model.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
          model.position.set(0,-0.5,0)
          scene.add(model)
          if (model) {
            model.traverse((child) => {
              if (child.isMesh) {
                const vertices = child.geometry.attributes.position;
                for (let i = 0; i < vertices.count; i++) {
                  const x = vertices.getX(i);
                  const y = vertices.getY(i);
                  const z = vertices.getZ(i);
    
                  const particle = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial());
                  particle.position.set(x, y, z);
                  particles.push(particle);
                  originalPositions.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
                  originalMaterials.push(particle.material.clone());
                }
              }
            });
            scene.add(...particles);
          }
        });
```

Comment: Add the particles into a THREE.Group and scale the group before you add it to the scene, that should do the trick iirc.